# Is it ever justifiable to write code without tests when doing TDD?

Tags: tdd

Is it ever justifiable to write production-code without also writing tests for it when doing Test Driven Development?

Comment: There may be circumstances when it's acceptable, but then it's not test-driven development.

Comment: I often do this when writing some small, trivial piece of code. If it starts to get more than trivial, I stop writing, test what I've done so far, then carry on with TDD. That's just me though, ymmv.

Comment: Do we assume the dev can actually write the test?

Comment: I never write tests for simple getters and setters, because if they're not working there's not much I can do about it anyway!

Comment: Tests are code, right? Does anyone ever write test tests?...

Comment: Is it ever acceptable to treat a methodology as a religion instead of a methodology?

Comment: Perhaps involving things like deadlock avoidance, multithreading mutex/semaphores, etc. However I think the list is pretty small and almost all the code surrounding them should be testable, especially when using IoC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strict TDD? Absolutely not. How can you write a test, make it fail, make it pass, without writing a test?

In the real world, very few people do strict TDD. It's an ideal that shouldn't be allowed to get in the way of common sense. Every rule has a scenario where it's justifiable to break it, and that's fine. But we shouldn't lie to ourselves or others and claim we do TDD when we don't. If for no other reason than it gives a bad impression of TDD, when it fails to achieve its goals.

(Replace TDD with any other process and the point stands.)

Also, the most common justification for not doing TDD is time. And that's very rarely a good reason.

If a change isn't complex, it shouldn't take long to write the test. If it is complex then you're inviting issues down the line by not writing tests first, so the time isn't often truly saved.

But, perhaps there is a justification even for that. Perhaps it's better to get something imperfect into the market and then fix it.

Without knowing the justification being disputed, it's hard to know whether it's valid. But I will reiterate that most rules can be broken, with good justification. As long as we're honest with ourselves about it and acknowledge when it turns out to be a mistake.

Comment: +1, although "not doing X" because of time can be a good reason. In essence "because of time" doesn't mean to save time, it means to allocate that time later rather than now. What it comes down to is amassing technical debt - it's just important to understand that that's happening. Like conventional debt, it has its use. While a particular task will actually consume more resources, the *overall effort* may be rendered more efficient/profitable. The only certainty is, that you will have to deal with the debt at some point.

Comment: @back2dos: That is exactly what I was trying to express with "Perhaps it's better to get something imperfect into the market and then fix it." But I have seen that line overused, many times, so I say it with a tone of caution.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your definition of "also writing tests", it may be acceptable :

- At the Refactor step. Refactoring doesn't require writing new tests (but does imply a test suite already in place)
- When you make adjustments in purely cosmetic UI code or other non directly testable code.
- Also, I won't write tests when I set up a preliminary quick and dirty 10- lines of code prototype to prove some technical detail is working. Here, TDD's feedback loop is slightly too long for what I want. But I guess that doesn't count as being inside of a normal TDD process. And I do delete this code and start a regular TDD cycle after.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by tests you mean 'unit tests', don't you?

TDD has its limitation, in particular you can't write unit tests for the parts of the system that depend on external components that you can't mock. Of course you can write tests but it would be different kind of tests with different level of granularity.

Comment: This is a purely hypothetical situation, so any type of test you could justify as still living up to being the testing part of TDD. Of course unit tests are the most likely candidate.

Comment: http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2014/01/27/TheChickenOrTheRoad.html Bob Martin has stopped referring to TDD tests as 'unit' tests.  Presumably to avoid such confusion.

Comment: @Scroog1 TDD never promised 'good architecture' - it's more about organisation of coding process. It's not for brilliant developers but for those who feel embarrassed of writing ugly and buggy code. I guess everybody remember mantra - don't refactor without unit tests. You also may drop word 'unit' but this is just a subjective definition of granularity level. If you write only one test for whole your system and state that this is TDD than this either means that your system is very simple or this is not TDD.